# How to convert UTC to typical date format in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, utc

I have this UTC column called Timestamp. It looks like this.

```
2019-06-27T23:01:12.1024861Z
```

How do I convert it so it looks like this in Excel?

```
06/27/2019 23:01:12
```

If there is a formula that would be best please leave it below as it must be applied to all cells in column

Answer (score 14):

Let's assume the input time is in cell `A1`. then you can convert it to Excel date and time value using the following formulae,

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8))
```

What this is doing is getting the date portion of the input using `LEFT(A1,10)` and converting it into `DATEVALUE` and getting the time portion using `MID(A1,12,8)` and converting it into `TIMEVALUE`. Add them together and you get date and time.

You can use Excel custom format and use the following:

```
mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use REPLACE to remove the T and Z:

```
=--REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,28,1,""),11,1," ")
```

Then format as desired.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**for german excel** users that should help:

cell F6: 2022-10-05T05:58:43.833Z

```
=DATWERT(LINKS(F6;10))+ZEITWERT(TEIL(F6;12;8))
```

formate cell: TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm:ss

result: *05.10.2022 05:58:43*

further to get unix timestamp:

```
=(M21-DATUM(1970;1;1))*86400
```

formate cell as regular number

result: *1664949523*